# Using a value from result to avoid double MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to get the "title" field if the "content" field contains a certain phrase. With the title I can do the actual query to get the posts.

-- psuedo code --

```
$query1 ='SELECT `title` FROM `posts` WHERE `content` CONTAINS 'matchtest' 
ORDER BY `id` ASC, LIMIT 1';
$titlefromquery1;

$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` = 'Reply to: ' . $titlefromquery1;
$repliesfromquery2;
```

The replies don't have the phrase to match fortunately the "`titles`" will always be "`Reply to: $title`" which is why both queries are needed it seems

Is there any way conditionally or otherwise to avoid a double query here?

Comment: pseudo code: self-join

Comment: I think, there is no other way. But you can change your system to INT. So that: You have posts so you can group replies and mains by parent_id parameter. with that you can group parent_id's and fetch with one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE title= 
concat_ws('Reply to: ',
(SELECT title FROM posts WHERE <put_your_condition> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use temporary variables to achieve this:

```
SELECT @title:=`title` FROM `posts` WHERE `content` CONTAINS 'matchtest' ORDER BY `id` ASC, LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` = CONCAT('Reply to: ' , @title);
```